# Probability proof, showing a equality holds

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Show that equality holds in $A(X^2) \ge A(X)^2$ iff $X(w_k)$ has same value for every k such that $p_k>0$ ie. for every category which actually occurs in the population, where
$A(X) = \dfrac 1 N \large\sum\limits_k n_k X_k(w_k) = \large\sum\limits_k p_k X(w_k)$

Comment: Do you mean $E(X^2)$ and $(E(X))^2$?

Comment: I mean $A(X^2)$ and $A(X)^2$ as A(X) defined as A(X) = $\frac 1N \sum_k n_kX(w_k) = \sum_kp_kX(w_k)$ thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took on one of the parts

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose that $X(w_k)=\alpha$ for all $k$ such that $p_k>0$. Letting $\sum_kp_k=p$. We see that $A(X^2)=\sum_kp_k(X(w_k))^2=\sum_kp_k\alpha^2=\alpha^2p$. We also have that $A(X)^2=\left(\sum_kp_kX(w_k)\right)^2=(\alpha p)^2=\alpha^2p^2$. Thus we have since $0<p<1$ that $A(X^2)=\alpha^2p\geq\alpha^2p^2=A(X)^2$

Im not completely sure either that other direction is always true. For example, what if $\{w_k\}=\{w_1=1,w_2=-1\}$ where $p_1=p_2=\frac{1}{2}$. But maybe this example doesn't fit what problem is saying, which if thats the cases could you please clarify why that is